# Is there a way to find an equivalent node inside another subtree in XSLT 1?

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

I have an xml document with two subtrees (`subtree A` and `subtree B`) as children of a `root` node. The document is dynamically generated and can be of varying depth and structure. But `subtree B` is guaranteed to be identical to `subtree A`, so for any descendant of `subtree A` there is guaranteed to be a descendant of `subtree B` with the same path relative to its subtree.

[image: Example XML document]

My goal is to render this document into PDF using xsl-fo. `Subtree A` contains the data I wish to render, while `subtree B` contains layout and other information which is required to render the data.

I'm using xslt to transform the xml document into xsl-fo, for later rendering.

During the xslt transformation, `subtree A` will be parsed and the structure and data contained will be used to generate xsl-fo.

My question is: Assuming the transformation is currently processing `/root/subtree A/alpha/1`, is there any way I can select the corresponding node in `subtree B`? I am hoping for some kind of xpath like `"replace(path(), 'subtree A', 'subtree B')"` or similar, but using only XSLT 1.0 capabilities.

Comment: It may be possible, but it won't be simple and it won't be pretty. Which XSLT 1.0 processor will you be using? It could be a lot easier if it supports some sort of `evaluate()` extension function.

Comment: It would also be easier if you can be sure that there will be no sibling elements with the same name. --- P.S. Note that `1` or `2` are not valid XML element names.

Answer (score 0):

Consider processing both subtrees in parallel. The nodes of A are processed through `xsl:apply-templates` statements and the parallel set of nodes from B is maintained in a template parameter named `B`.

The following stylesheet has just one template for A (`match="*"`), but you could have several for different nodes of A. What's important is that they all include the same statements `<xsl:param name="B">` and `<xsl:with-param name="B">`.

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="A">
      <xsl:with-param name="B" select="B" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:param name="B" />
    <xsl:variable name="positionA" select="position()" />
    <xsl:variable name="curB" select="$B[position() = $positionA]" />
    <!-- The current() node from A now corresponds to $curB. -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
      <xsl:with-param name="B" select="$curB/*" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Recursion need not always happen with `<xsl:apply-templates select="*">`, it could also be like

```xml
<xsl:apply-templates select="beta | gamma">
  <xsl:with-param name="B" select="$curB/beta | $curB/gamma" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
```